# Time for the Dessert!

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

*The answer is one word.*

[image] [image] [image]

[image] [image] [image]

Hint 1:

> I've added a "cipher" tag.

Hint 2:

> Had I been content with less mouth-watering desserts, I could have used this pic for the top middle slot:
>  
>  [image]

Comment: After seeing all this, the only word which comes to mind is food :D

Comment: @ABcDexter Admittedly it might not have been wise to put together this puzzle the first thing in the morning (my time), now all I can think of is food :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer is

> LIQUOR

Because each image

> resembles a letter from the [maritime signal flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_maritime_signal_flags) alphabet!

Comment: Great answer! I had no idea how to solve this.

Comment: +1 Wow, I would've never thought of this. Also props for OP pretty accurate images, now that I saw rot13(gur bevtvany syntf).

Comment: Yeah, finding the right images took forever - but then, it's not terribly painful looking at hundreds of pictures of glorious desserts picking just the right one :-)

Answer (score 3):

Partial:
Image 1:

> Apparently this is a chocolate and vanilla Battenberg Cake, which I have never heard of before. Looks like there is some sort of raspberry (presumably) jelly or something to glue the pieces together.

2:

> Uhh... I'm not too familiar with macaroons to begin with, but at least the little one on top appears to be a macaroon. So, what's the big ol' base and the cookie halves for? Plus, there's just ONE blueberry... And *what* is that black thing? Makes it look like a candle pastry!

3:

> A mango dome entremet OR a mango mousse dome? What?

4:

> Another battenberg cake, but this time white chocolate, raspberry, and vanilla (I think).

5:

> Cut/sliced mango and strawberries.

6:

> This is nifty looking. I guess it's a well done raspberry and (white) chocolate (or, maybe it's fondant, however that's actually spelled) sponge cake.

How this all relates:

> Hah! No idea other than them all being forms of deserts. (Well 5 is only fruit you say. Well fruit can be considered desert, probably more commonly so outside of the states I say).
>  (Note, I forgot about the title. Yeah, they're deserts. Great observation.)

Comment: These observations are fairly accurate but don't really help you...

Comment: Indeed. I had hoped that figuring out what each thing was would help, but that didn't pan out. Had considered deleting the answer all-together. Still might.

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant at all, but the cookies on 2 are macarons, not macaroons. Confusingly, a macaroon is also a type of cookie but is entirely different :)

Comment: Wow! What a trip. Thanks @BriarHarrison.

Answer (score 3):

Images in order from left to right top then left to right bottom

1.

> [Chocolate Battenburg Cake](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/300615343852347727/)

2.

> Presumably: Macaron (French Macaroon)

3.

> [Mango Mousse Cake](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/491244271832139734/)

4.

> [BATTENBERG CAKE PAN](https://www.pastrychef.com/STAX-PAN-BATTENBERG-CAKE-PAN_p_3221.html)

5.

> [Strawberry Mango Crisp](https://thecaringcoachingcenter.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/fresh-strawberry-mango-smoothie-fruit.jpg)

6.

> [Jewel Box Cake](https://thehappyfoodie.co.uk/recipes/jewel-box-cake)

I would say that they're

> ***Dessert***

Comment: Er, yes, that's the title of the puzzle :-) Not the answer.

Comment: I notice that the top picture row had a sponge like in common, and the bottom row was fruits. Not sure if that related

Comment: Not related, no.